# Send message to disconnected user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, socket.io

so, as you may know there is an [admin-ui library](https://socket.io/docs/v4/admin-ui/) (Idk what to call it) in socket.io.
what I want to do is if a client is kicked, send a message to that client (or have the client detect when it is disconnected)
i have tried:

```js
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  alert('disconnected');
});
```

but that does nothing...

Comment: Is this on the client or the server..?

Comment: @caTS I want to send it to the client that disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix using the socket attribute [`connected`](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-offline-behavior/) and setting an interval to check if the client is connected to a socket:

```js
// client
let offline_alerted = false;
setInterval(function () {
    if (socket.connected === false) {
        if (offline_alerted === false) {
            alert("Disconnected :(");
            offline_alerted = true;
        }
    } else if (offline_alerted === true) {
        alert("Reconnected!");
        offline_alerted = false;
    }
}, 1000);
```